# access frame's document using GWT

Tags: gwt

I have a GWT application, which has a frame to point to other web url, like this: frame.setUrl(other web url);

but sometimes there might be error from other web url, say network error, or page not available, i need to parse out those error and present a user friendly error message in my GWT application, but could not figure out how to do that with the frame, i tried :

```
frame.addDomHandler(new LoadHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
                Window.alert("loaded!");

                IFrameElement iframe = IFrameElement.as(frame.getElement());
                Document frameDocument = getIFrameDocument(iframe);
                if (frameDocument != null) {
                    Window.alert(frameDocument.getDomain());
                }
                else {
                    Window.alert("the document is empty, nothing to display!");
                }

            }
        }, LoadEvent.getType());
    }

    private native Document getIFrameDocument(IFrameElement iframe) /*-{
        return iframe.contentDocument;
    }-*/;
```

it always return document as null, i guess that's because of same-orign policy. so how can i  access the frame document in GWT? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using your native `getIFrameDocument()` JSNI method, try calling `iframe.getContentDocument()` on the `IFrameElement` provided by GWT. Here's [the javadoc for that method](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/IFrameElement.html).